# open warc file with python

Tags: python-2.7, warc

I'm trying to open a warc file with python using the toolbox from the following link:
http://warc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

When opening the file with:

```
import warc
f = warc.open("00.warc.gz")
```

Everything is fine and the f object is:

```
<warc.warc.WARCFile instance at 0x1151d34d0>
```

However when I'm trying to read everything in the file using:

```
for record in f:
     print record['WARC-Target-URI'], record['Content-Length']
```

The following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warc/warc.py", line 390, in         __iter__
record = self.read_record()
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warc/warc.py", line 373, in read_record
header = self.read_header(fileobj)
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warc/warc.py", line 331, in read_header
raise IOError("Bad version line: %r" % version_line)
IOError: Bad version line: 'WARC/0.18\n'
```

Is this because my warc file version is not supported by the warc toolbox I'm using or something else?

Comment: That's what the error says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ClueWeb09 dataset is available in the WARC 0.18 format. However, it has several issues. Some records are [malformed](http://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/docs/content/clue.html#malformed).

> The most prevalent problem is an extra newline in the WARC header. There are a few cases of other malformed headers also.

Moreover, it does not use the standard \r\n end-of-line markers which is actually your problem.

[warc-clueweb library](https://github.com/cdegroc/warc-clueweb) can handle it. This is a special python library to work with ClueWeb09 WARC files. According to documentation

> Only minor modifications to the original library were made. The original documentation of the warc library still holds

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Sorry for the delay but I put this project aside for now. But I will test this as soon as I come back to it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks for @eyelash explanation about this problem.

Actually some records in Clueweb-09 are malformed. But the official [warc](http://warc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library and the above recommended git repo [warc-clueweb library](https://github.com/cdegroc/warc-clueweb) both have some issues.

This fork repo could not handle Clueweb12 dataset and another issue is that it could miss 1-2 document when dealing every .warc.gz file.

So I've changed a little code to support both Clueweb09 and Cluewe12 datasets. Here is my repo which has been tested on 100 billion pages, [my warc tools](https://github.com/RominYue/warc) forked and changed from warc-clueweb library and official repo.