# Read warc file with python

Tags: python, warc

I want to read a warc file and I wrote the follwoing code based on [this page](http://warc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but nothing was printted!!

```
>>import warc
>>f = warc.open("01.warc.gz")
>>for record in f:
    print record['WARC-Target-URI'], record['Content-Length']
```

However, when I wrote the following command I got result

```
>>print f
<warc.warc.WARCFile instance at 0x0000000002C7DE88>
```

Note that my warc file is one of the file from Clueweb09 dataset. I mentioned it because of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784825/open-warc-file-with-python).

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer to the question you linked to has a solution.  Did you try that?

Comment: @cco the first box of code does not print.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you.

After some research on the module, I found a solution.

Try to use `record.payload.read()`, here is full example:

```
import warc
f = warc.open("01.warc.gz")
for record in f:
  print record.payload.read()
```

Also, I can say that you can not only read `warc` files, but `wet` too. Small cheat is to renaming it to name, that contains `.warc`

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all, WARC, or Web ARChive, is an archival format for web pages.
Reading a `warc` file is a bit tricky because it contains some special header.
Assuming your `warc` file is of [this format](https://gist.github.com/mic0331/908773fe455d838cf1a028f0549ad2e0).

You can use the following code to load, parse and return a dictionary for every record containing the metadata and the content.

```
def read_header(file_handler):
    header = {}
    line = next(file_handler)
    while line != '\n':
        key, value = line.split(': ', 1)
        header[key] = value.rstrip()
        line = next(file_handler)
    return header


def warc_records(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        while True:
            line = next(fh)
            if line == 'WARC/1.0\n':
                output = read_header(fh)
                if 'WARC-Refers-To' not in output:
                    continue
                output["Content"] = next(fh)
                yield output
```

You can access the dictionary as follow:

```
records = warc_records("<some path>')
>>> next_record = next(records)
>>> sorted(next_record.keys())
['Content', 'Content-Length', 'Content-Type', 'WARC-Block-Digest', 'WARC-Date', 'WARC-Record-ID', 'WARC-Refers-To', 'WARC-Target-URI', 'WARC-Type', 'WARC-Warcinfo-ID']
>>> next_record['WARC-Date']
'2013-06-20T00:32:15Z'
>>> next_record['WARC-Target-URI']
'http://09231204.tumblr.com/post/44534196170/high-res-new-photos-of-the-cast-of-neilhimself'
>>> next_record['Content'][:30]
'Side Effects high res. New pho'
```